# Keyboard layout randomly changes when I start VS Code or Sublime Text 3

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, cinnamon, ibus, sublime-text

I have a big and annoying problem, my keyboard layout changes to `se` when I start VS Code or Sublime Text 3.

To fix it, I created simple lines in `.zshrc` but this is not right way to fix this problem!

```
vscodePath=$(which code)

function code {
    "${vscodePath}" $@;
    sleep 3;
    ~/fixkeyboard.sh
}

sublPath=$(which subl);

function subl {
    "${sublPath}" $@;
    sleep 3;
    ~/fixkeyboard.sh
}



# ~/fixkeyboard.sh
#!/bin/bash
setxkbmap us,ru
setxkbmap -option caps:none
python -c 'from ctypes import *; X11 = cdll.LoadLibrary("libX11.so.6"); display = X11.XOpenDisplay(None); X11.XkbLockModifiers(display, c_uint(0x0100), c_uint(2), c_uint(0)); X11.XCloseDisplay(display)'
```

I have tried to google it, tried again and nothing from what I got helped me.

Ubuntu 16.04, Cinnamon DE, IBus (just for info)

Comment: Have you check the .desktop files for Sublime Text and VS Code? If you launch those programs from terminal, does the problem persist?

Comment: @PyGeek03, yes. No matter how you open those programs, your keyboard layout will reset to `se` immediately after the start of VS Code and after some time in Sublime Text 3